# Конфликт в области "innerHTML"

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код всплавающей формы (с проверкой заполнения):

```
function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,former,url) { 
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: "submit.php",
        type:     "POST", 
        dataType: "html", 
        data: jQuery("#"+former).serialize(),  
        success: function(response) {  
            document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response; 
        }, 
        error: function(response) { 
            document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "Ошибка при отправке формы"; 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

А также main.js (скрипт навигации по всему сайту), который идет в конце страницы. 
оба кода отдельно работают нормально. Пробовал в разные места (выше, позже, даже внутрь "main.js") вставить верхний код, работает также, а то и еще хуже.

Проблема: при объединении обеих упирается в ошибки:

> "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of
> null" в строке 08 и "undefined is not
> a function"

В строке 97 в feedback.js (скрипт обработки кнопки). Вопрос: с чего начать соединение двух скриптов в рабочую форму в даном примере?

Answer (score 2):

тут можно посоветовать сделать следующее:

1. замыкания, чтобы область тех скриптов, которые независимы друг от друга, ни в коем случае не пересекалась
2. раз уж используете jQuery, то используйте его до конца, т.е никаких document.getElementById, innerHTML и т.п

Comment: поменял document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response на "$('#'+result_id).html(response)"
Но теперь не работает строчка №3 - url: "submit.php"
с JS не дружу, пытался добавить url, а именно $('#'+result_id+url).html(response); 
но это не работает. Посоветуйте  дельное

Comment: выложите весь js-код, который получился, в идеале вместе html-кодом страницы. можете залить архив на бесплатный хостинг и дать ссылку. тогда я смогу вам помочь

Comment: http://chartorijskiy.16mb.com/dasser/down-er.rar там пачка JS и htm. Последняя (единственная) ошибка в feedback.js 125 строка. у меня мозг отказываэт, тем более с JS только поверхностно работал

Comment: как именно проявляется ошибка? на строке, которую вы указали просто вызов jquery-плагина и ошибок там нет, по крайней мере синтаксических

Comment: после нажатия на submit заполненой формы срабатывает index.php который запускаеться feedback.js в папке feedback. После чего даные  формы оправляеться на почту и кнопка замирает (становиться не активной), а в хроме вываливает ошибку - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Но submit.php  не срабабатывает.

Answer (score 1):

Вам говорят, результат выражения document.getElementById(result_id) - null. Т.е. элемент с таким идентификатором не найден. Соединение скриптов тут не причём.